# Nextjs next-session storage other than memory

Tags: node.js, session, next.js, server-side-rendering

I don’t find any resource or package to use another storage other than memory for next-session, where memory is not a suitable solution for production?

I want to use either file storage ( preferred ) or db .

Comment: `next-session` provides a `store` option that can be overwritten. See https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-session#session-store.

Comment: I’m not able to do it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store session for example in sqlite3.

1. install sqlite 'npm install connect-sqlite3'
2. Create a new file for example 'get-session.js' and write this:

> ```
> import nextSession from "next-session";
> import { expressSession, promisifyStore } from "next-session/lib/compat";
> var SQLiteStore = require("connect-sqlite3")(expressSession);
>
> export const getSession = nextSession({
>   name: "WIB_SESSION",
>   store: promisifyStore(
>     new SQLiteStore({ dir: "./tmp/", table: "wiberSessions" })
>   ),
> });
> ```

3. Create a new api endpoint and put this.

> ```
> import { getSession } from "../../lib/get-session.js";
> export default async function handler(req, res) {
>   const session = await getSession(req, res);
>   const data={hello:"hello im a data in session"}
>   session.myData= data
>
>   res.status(200).json({save:"session saved"});
> }
> export const config = {
>   api: {
>     externalResolver: true,
>   },
> };
> ```

4. And now from your Page

> ```
> import { getSession } from "../lib/get-session";
>
> export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
>   const session = await getSession(req, res);
>
>   return {
>     props: {
>       dataInSession: session.myData,
>
>     },
>   };
> }
> ```

Now you will have a cookie named "WIB_SESSION" with a value, and the data stored in a database SQLITE in ./tmp/wiberSessions.

Here you have a basic project with next.
[Github](https://github.com/HastaCs/next_session_sqlite)

First time you load the page,
[First Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlrsQ.png)
And when you press the button and reload the page you have the cooki and the value from the /tmp/sqlite.[withcookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Alz.png)

Greetings

Comment: Have a nice day! Can you please tell me where to list cookieOptions: :maxAge, httpOnly, secure and so on? After this property: store: promisifyStore(
    new SQLiteStore({ dir: "./tmp/", table: "wiberSessions" }
  ),?

Comment: Hi.. here  

  store: promisifyStore(new SQLiteStore({ dir: "./tmp/", table: "wiberSessions" })),
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 80000,
  },

you have all options in documentation.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-session